# Concerning functions (maps) and n-fold composition

Tags: group-theory, elementary-set-theory

I'm hoping to understand what the theorem below is saying and maybe receive hints but not the full proof. Apparently group theory can be used and I see that the function $f$ is closed as groups should. Also, a group has an identity $i,$ where $i*i$ should of course give $i.$ It appears $i$ in this case is $g.$

Let $S$ be a finite set and $f: S\to S$ a function. Show that there is an integer $n > 0$ such that if $g = f^n$ (the $n$-fold composite of $f$), then $g^2= g$ (i.e. $g$ is idempotent).

Comment: It is true, the word "set" appears in the question, but that doesn't mean it fits under the [tag:set-theory] tag.

Comment: It came from a chapter in a book entitled set-theory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have $f[S]\subseteq S.$  By induction we see that $f^{n+1}[S]\subseteq f^n[S].$ Let $T=\bigcap f^n[S].$ Show that there is a minimal $m\in\Bbb N$ such that $T=f^m[S]$ and that $f|_T:T\to T$ is a bijection.

Now, $f|_T$ is an element of the permutation group of $T,$ and as such it has an order $k.$ Try to find an $l$ depending on $k$ and $m$ such that $f^{2l}=f^{l}.$

Comment: Thanks for the help but my math background is definitely not that advanced. Do you think you could explain that with less notation?

Comment: @inkievoyd: Where exactly do you have problems? Is the first paragraph clear?

Comment: I think that I understand all the terms and for lack of better word, the vocabulary that you've used but I only understand them individually, not how they relate. The first paragraph is clear except I don't see the bijection.

Comment: We have the sequence $S\supset f[S]\supset f^2[S]\supset...\supset f^m[S]=f^{m+1}[S]$ because in a finite set there cannot be an infinite nested sequence of sets (one also says the sequence becomes *stationary*). But $f[f^m[S]]=f^m[S]$ means that $f$ is surjective on $T=f^m[S]$. On a finite set this implies bijectivity.

Comment: Bijections on a set (also called *permutations*) form a group under composition $(f,g)\mapsto f\circ g$ with the identity function as unity. Since $T$ is finite, this group Perm$(T)$ is finite, so $f|_T$ has an order, a minimal $k$ such that $(f|_T)^k=\mathrm{Id}_T.$

Comment: Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: @inkievoyd: You are welcome! If you have any question regarding the $l$, feel free to ask.